# how to get the link names of a webpage using cURL command

Tags: http, curl, get, postman

I am using Postman, a google Chrome add on that makes cURL commands, and I make a GET command with a website url. My question goes with an example: on a website like google, if i type "stackoverflow" and search, I take this url and make my cURL command, how can I get the names of each link? Is that possible? By example, for this page there would be "Stack Overflow" ... "Stack Overflow - Wikipédia"...

Comment: What does your current code look like, and what issues do you have with it?

Comment: Postman don't have code, you enter url, the type of command (here I put GET), the headers (not needed here) and you have the website in http. But there is some information that I can't get, has described on the topic. I want to know how to get it if it is possible, I haven't found by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer by myself.
I installed Postman Interceptor, activated it and entered the website on google chrome. The interceptor sent all the requests done to get that website to my postman, so all i had to do is look at them and I found the information I looked for in one of them.